# how to generate rules from decision tree in data mining?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, decision-tree

I have code to create decision tree from data set. i am using weather data set in weka examples. how can i generate the rules from the decision tree in java?

Data set::

```
@relation weather

@attribute outlook {sunny, overcast, rainy}
@attribute temperature real
@attribute humidity real
@attribute windy {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute play {yes, no}

@data
sunny,85,85,FALSE,no
sunny,80,90,TRUE,no
overcast,83,86,FALSE,yes
rainy,70,96,FALSE,yes
rainy,68,80,FALSE,yes
rainy,65,70,TRUE,no
overcast,64,65,TRUE,yes
sunny,72,95,FALSE,no
sunny,69,70,FALSE,yes
rainy,75,80,FALSE,yes
sunny,75,70,TRUE,yes
overcast,72,90,TRUE,yes
overcast,81,75,FALSE,yes
rainy,71,91,TRUE,no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get decision rules from a tree by following the path to each leaf and connecting the conditions on the junctions with "and". That is, for each leaf you would end up with one rule that tells you what conditions must be met to get to that leaf.

It might be easier though to instead of training a tree train a set of decision rules directly, e.g. with the `DecisionTable` classifier.